# Non web-based Twitter Client?

Tags: networking

Can anybody point me to a twitter client for the Raspberry Pi?

I'd like to use this for an event that I will be doing IT for. The idea is to have an unattended Rpi hooked up to a projector which will display certain search-terms.

People at the event can tweet to a hash-tag in order to display something on the screen.

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:** I should clarify. This will be a social event where a lot of (non technical) people will be gathering in a bar, drinking over-priced beverages, observing some kind of cabaret acts, etc.

The event organizers wanted to give the event a "hashtag", (e.g. #fooevent).

The idea of this display is that any time somebody in the bar writes a tweet, we'd like it to appear on the screen after a short delay. It ought to be formatted nicely along with the user's icon.

By "non web-based", I meant not accessing Twitter via a web-browser. Some kind of twitter-client that can provide a more customized on-screen experience.

One idea was to hack Gwibbler, but I was hoping to spend not that much time on this project.

Answer (score 6):

[Try T](http://sferik.github.com/t/). It's a Twitter CLI client, written in Ruby.

Comment: Neat, but not what I'm after. T does not appear to have any kind of GUI (it's a pure CLI client), which means it's not going to look all that good for a non-technical audience on those projectors!

Comment: @SalimFadhley Define `non-web` based then?

Comment: I've clarified above.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own in 'talking twitter client' Python using twitter streaming api.  The streaming api might be a better solution for your display, as you wouldn't have to wait or poll for new results as twitter would stream the tweet to your client in realtime.

The client I wrote is not much more than a proof of concept, but it might give you a starting point, see [stuffaboutcode.com talking twitter client](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/10/raspberry-pi-python-talking-twitter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.sbprojects.com/projects/raspberrypi/tweet.php

Simply;

- Get API account from supertweet.net
- install CURL
- run the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [twitter clients](http://www.techmynd.com/25-best-twitter-linux-apps/) available for linux, many of which have GUI interfaces.  I haven't used any of these, but according to its website [Choqok](http://choqok.gnufolks.org/) supports the search API, so is probably something like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Twirssi](http://twirssi.com/) in the past, it's a Twitter extension written for [irssi](http://www.irssi.org/).

Please note that I haven't used it for over a year, but based on the [Twitter feed of the author](https://twitter.com/#!/twirssi) it is still active and functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Python is really well supported on the RPi, you should probably look at the python Twitter API which is easy to integrate for the suggested projector use.

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ for more details.

And you can install it on your device by doing:

```
sudo pip install python-twitter
```